# Is every android phone has en_US locale?

Tags: android, locale

I wonder is every android phone has the `en_US` locale preinstalled? I have to pre-set the `Locale` in order to prevent comma separator issue.

Currently, I'm using the method below to force change, but I worried exceptions might happen on some devices.

```
            Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They most likely have it.

In case you would like to check regardless, you could do something like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
List availableLocales = Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales());

if(!availableLocales.contains(locale)) {
    // en_US locale not available, do your stuff here accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder is every android phone has en_US locale preinstalled?

99.99% will have it.

Comment: I agree, it's very unlikely that a Android device doesn't have that locale. But non the less it is a possibility that it's missing.